# My proof that $X= \left \{ \left (\dfrac{1}{a},a \right) \in \mathbb{R}^2: a \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have to prove that $X= \left \{ \left (\dfrac{1}{a},a \right) \in \mathbb{R}^2: a \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ is closed.

This is my idea, I supposed that $\overline{X} \not\subset X$ then exists $(x,y) \in \overline{X}$ such that $(x,y) \notin X$. If $(x,y) \notin X$ then $(x,y) \neq \left (\dfrac{1}{a},a \right) \ \forall a \in \mathbb{N}$, then $x \neq \dfrac{1}{a}$ or $y \neq a$.

And $(x,y) \in \overline{X}$ so $\forall r>0$ $B((x,y), r) \cap X \neq \emptyset$ then exists $(m,n) \in B((x,y), r) \cap X$, if $x \neq \dfrac{1}{a}$ then $\vert x -\dfrac{1}{a} \vert >0$. Taking $r=\vert x -\dfrac{1}{a} \vert$ we have $(m,n) \in B((x,y), \vert x -\dfrac{1}{a} \vert) \cap X$.

So $\sqrt{(m-x)^2+(n-y)^2}<r$ and $(m,n) \in X$ so $m=\dfrac{1}{b} $ and $n=b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $x \neq \dfrac{1}{b}$ then $\vert x -\dfrac{1}{b} \vert >0$. Taking $r=\vert x -\dfrac{1}{b} \vert$ we have $\sqrt{(\dfrac{1}{b}-x)^2+(b-y)^2}< \vert x -\dfrac{1}{b} \vert$ then $(b-y)^2 <0$ a contradiction.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Another way: it is the intersection of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb N$ with $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : xy = 1\}$.  The intersection of two closed sets in $\mathbb R^2$ remains closed.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler idea - the distance between any two points in $X$ is greater than 1, so $X$ is a discrete set (i.e. has only isolated points) and is hence closed.